# XMPPFramework/iOS issue: send and receive subscription

Tags: ios, xmpp, xmppframework

I have a challenge with XMPPFramework today...

I've configured ejabberd correctly: server is up and running and registering users correctly by in-band registration.

But when I try to send a subscription request from one device, the second one can't recieve the presence for the first one. Here's the code I use on the first device to subscribe to a user, as documented:

```
[[[self appDelegate] xmppRoster] addUser:userJID withNickname:nickname groups:nil subscribeToPresence:YES];
```

And if everything goes ok, the second device must fire the delegate method:

```
- (void)xmppRoster:(XMPPRoster *)sender didReceiveBuddyRequest:(XMPPPresence *)presence
```

The problem is that this delegate method is never fired.
The server creates the new contact for the user, I can see it on ejabberd web administrator, but the subscription type is set to none.

Any ideas?

**UPDATE:**

Well, it seems that I was forgetting to include the hostname into the JID. Now, the delegates for XMPPRoster are not being called, but I can see on ejabberd that the request is not 'none' but 'both' and pending validation.

Can't imagine why the XMPPRoster delegates are not firing... it seems that ejabberd server don't send the proper notification when a user receives a new subscription request...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that eJabberd was misconfigured or something. Just installed OpenFire and everything works correctly.

Comment: Hey Yoryo, I am facing the same problem, I using open fire, but not getting the presence of one user. please help, its urgent

Comment: Well I'm not working with this XMPPFramework project anymore, but I remember that OpenFire has a user management tool for users. Maybe you must review the stanzas you are getting from the delegate methods. You can read about this here: https://github.com/robbiehanson/XMPPFramework/wiki/IntroToFramework

Comment: I have reason to believe that OpenFire may have a way of resolving the "resource" part of the JID, which ejabberd does not. When the resource part of the JID is added and subscribed, the delegate methods fire.